# JQuery deferred and websocket

Tags: jquery, websocket, jquery-deferred

I'm new to websocket and deferred functions so excuse me if this is stupid.

As I understand the deferred is use when you start a function and want that another start when the first is finished.

I have a websocket sending two events. On the client side an ajax request is called to get html code to insert in the page. I need that the firs event code from its ajax resquest be inserted before inserting the one from the second event. The first one is not always sent but when it is the 2 events are very closed and i got :

- receive evt1
- receive evt2
- construct html2
- construct html1

So i want to execute evt2 code after evt1 code is finished.

- receive evt2

  - if evt1 received and not ended wait
  - else execute

UPDATE

Here's how i resolve my problem, don't know if it's the best way but it works.

```
var evt1_promise = 0 ;
function evt1_fct(topic, data)
{
 evt1_promise = $.Deferred() ;

 $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "php/html_evt1.php", async: false }).done(function(data) { $(".Container").html(data) ; evt1_promise.resolve() }) ;
}

function evt2_fct(topic, data)
{
 // In case there's no event 1 started
 if(!evt1_promise)
 {
  evt1_promise = $.Deferred() ;
  evt1.resolve() ;
 }

 evt1_promise.done(function()
 {
  $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "php/quizz_start.php", data: datas, async: false }).done(function (data) { $(".Quizz").html(data) } }) ;
 }) ;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you using ajax or websockets, it's not the same thing ?

Comment: Both, I request html pages elements by ajax and use ws for computing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Async.js https://github.com/caolan/async. A great library for making asynchronous requests and working with the results when they come in. For your case you could use Async.parallel, which would fire both requests off and call the callback when *both* results are in (in a results array).

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use a library, you could cache the results from each ajax call, then run a check each time a call returned to make sure you only construct your html once both calls have completed:

- have a callback that checks the size of a results array
- pass this as the callback to both ajax requests
- when results array size is 2 (or number of requests you've made) run the html construction code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery Deferred for websockets, have a look at https://github.com/jbloemendal/jquery-simple-websocket.

You can do things like:

```
var webSocket = $.simpleWebSocket({ url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:3000/' });

webSocket.listen(function(message) {
    console.log(message.text);
});

webSocket.send({ 'text': 'hello' }).done(function() {
   // message send
}).fail(function(e) {
   // error sending
});
```